# How do I fill a gui JTable with an ArrayList that is dynamic?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

So, I am trying to make a gui with a JTable that displays an ArrayList. This ArrayList in turn is supposed to be filled dynamically in the actual gui.

To be more specific, I'm trying to write a program which lets you add people and bank accounts to those people. I then want to display which person owns what accounts in a JTable.

I know there are some things very wrong in the code, that because I have been trying different things to solve this, which has so far only ended up giving me a headache.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Like really really really appreciated.

My code so far:

Controller Class

```
package org.lu.ics.inlämningsuppgifter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Controller  {
PersonRegister persons;
JFrame frame;

public Controller (PersonRegister personReg, JFrame frame) {
    this.persons=personReg;
    this.frame=frame;
}

public void addPerson (String pNbr, String pName) {
    Person tmpPerson = new Person(pNbr, pName);
    persons.addPerson(tmpPerson);
}

public void addPersonAccount (String pNbr, String pName, String accNbr) {
    Person tmpPerson = new Person(pNbr, pName);
    Account account = new Account(accNbr);
    tmpPerson.setAccounts(account);

}
public String[] findPerson(String pNbrFind) {
     Person p;
     String[] aPerson = null;
     p = persons.findPerson(pNbrFind);
     if (p != null && p.getAccounts() != null) {
     aPerson = new String[4];
     aPerson[0] = p.getPNbr();
     aPerson[1] = p.getName();
     aPerson[2] = p.getAccounts();
     } else if (p != null) {
     aPerson = new String[2];
     aPerson[0] = p.getPNbr();
     aPerson[1] = p.getName();
     }
     return aPerson;
     }


}
```

Account Class

```
package org.lu.ics.inlämningsuppgifter;

public class Account {

private String nbr;
private double balance; 
private Person owner;

public Person getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(Person newOwner) {
    owner = newOwner;
}

public void setNbr(String newNbr) {
    nbr = newNbr;
}

public String getNbr() {
    return nbr;
}

public Account (String accNbr) {
    balance = 0.00;
    this.setNbr(accNbr);

}

public void setBalance(double newBalance) {
    balance = newBalance;
    this.setBalance(newBalance);

}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void credit(double amount) {
    balance = balance + amount;
}

public void withdraw(double amount) {
    balance = balance - amount;
}


}
```

Person Class
    package org.lu.ics.inlämningsuppgifter;

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person {

private String pNbr;
private String name;
private ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

public Person(String pNbr, String pName) {
    this.setPNbr(pNbr);
    this.setName(pName);
}

public ArrayList<Account> getAccount() {
    return accounts;
}

public void setPNbr(String newPNbr) {
    pNbr = newPNbr;
}

public String getPNbr() {
    return pNbr;
}

public void setName(String newName) {
    name = newName;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setAccounts(ArrayList<Account> newAccounts) {
    accounts = newAccounts;
}

public ArrayList<Account> getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}

public void addAccount(Account anAccount) {
    this.getAccounts().add(anAccount);
}


}
```

PersonApplication Class (stupid name, I know)

```
package org.lu.ics.inlämningsuppgifter;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class PersonApplication {

private JFrame frame;
private final JTable tblAccounts = new JTable();
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_AccNbr;

private Controller controller;
private PersonRegister personRegister;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                PersonApplication window = new PersonApplication();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public PersonApplication() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Accounts");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 840, 524);
    frame.getContentPane();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    String col[] = {"Account", "Balance"};

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(col, 2);

    JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

    JButton btnAddPerson = new JButton("Add person");
    btnAddPerson.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    btnAddPerson.setBounds(35, 296, 105, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAddPerson);

    JButton btnRemovePerson = new JButton("Remove person");
    btnRemovePerson.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    btnRemovePerson.setBounds(35, 330, 107, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnRemovePerson);

    JButton btnFindPerson = new JButton("Find person");
    btnFindPerson.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String accNumber = textField_AccNbr.getText();
            //String[] tmpCustomer = controller.
        }
    });
    btnFindPerson.setBounds(35, 364, 91, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnFindPerson);

    JButton btnAddAccount = new JButton("Add Account");
    btnAddAccount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    btnAddAccount.setBounds(269, 296, 99, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAddAccount);

    JButton btnShowAccount = new JButton("Show Accounts");
    btnShowAccount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) 
 tblAccounts.getModel();

        }
    });
    btnShowAccount.setBounds(439, 451, 105, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnShowAccount);
    tblAccounts.setBounds(439, 300, 352, 132);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tblAccounts);

    JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
    lblName.setBounds(47, 29, 31, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblName);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(139, 26, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblPnmbr = new JLabel("PNmbr:");
    lblPnmbr.setBounds(47, 57, 35, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPnmbr);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(139, 51, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblAccountNumber = new JLabel("Account number:");
    lblAccountNumber.setBounds(47, 90, 82, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblAccountNumber);

    textField_AccNbr = new JTextField();
    textField_AccNbr.setBounds(139, 87, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_AccNbr);
    textField_AccNbr.setColumns(10);
}
}
```

PersonRegister Class

```
package org.lu.ics.inlämningsuppgifter;

import java.util.*;

public class PersonRegister {

private ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

public ArrayList<Person> getPersoner() {
    return persons;
}

public void setPersons(ArrayList<Person> newPersons) {
    persons = newPersons;
}

public void addPerson(Person newPerson) {
    persons.add(newPerson);
}

public Person findPerson(String pNbr) {
    for (Person p : this.persons) {
        if (p.getPNbr().equals(pNbr)) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public Person removePerson(String pNbr) {
    Person p = findPerson(pNbr);
    if (p != null) {
        persons.remove(p);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to make a gui with a JTable that displays an ArrayList. This ArrayList in turn is supposed to be filled dynamically in the actual gui.

The problem is that Swing works with models, not ArrayLists. So in particular you need to create a custom TableModel to hold your data. This model can use an ArrayList to hold the data but your application should never work directly with the ArrayList. You add/remove data by using methods of the model.

Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step example on how to create a custom TableModel that holds Person objects internally in an ArrayList.

Your `PersonRegister` class is replaced by a PersonTableModel class and all its necessary methods and custom methods.

Comment: So I should replace PersonRegister with PersonTableModel?

Comment: @Heeiman, oops, forgot the link to "Row Table Model". Check out the link for the example to get you started.